# Database Access from iOS App

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, mongodb

I've an iOS app that interacts with a custom API, that in turn interacts with the DB. I was thinking to eliminate the custom API step and access the DB directly from the iOS application (MongoDB).

Now several questions emerged:

- It would be a security issue to distribute login credentials (even if they're encrypted) with the app.
- I guess due to flaky networks the DB could be corrupted if designed improperly.
- Are there any real world examples where a database backend is directly accessed from Cocoa?

Basically it boils down to yes or no - and why.

PS: The database resides on the web, not an intranet/corporate network

Comment: What sort of app is it? I mean, is it for use within a corporate network? Or is it getting data over the internet? Or, does it use the built in DB? If the last, does the built in DB have a generic user that you might be able to use, or could you create one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are pros and cons.  I think you listed all the cons.  IMO, there are no pros other than having one less layer to maintain.  However, if you think this particular database will ever be accessed by anything other than the iOS app, you might as well go ahead and do the intermediate layer - you're going to need it eventually.  Might as well plan for it at the outset.

Comment: yes, but thats a big pro - not having to maintain an additional code layer.

Comment: If that outweighs the cons, go for it!  I personally haven't encountered a situation yet where it was a worthwhile tradeoff, but every situation is unique.

Answer (score 0):

I'd look at using a framework like [RailsKit](http://railskits.com/) to take care of the work.

As a proof-of-concept, we built an app that connected directly with a Rails backend, and the syncing worked well --- except that it was a bit of a pain to make it play nice: the interface would freeze while it waited for confirmation from the DB, etc.

So we're going to use an existing, available framework to take care of that work for us, and focus our development efforts on the interface and user experience.